# Open every link in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, anchor

I know I can open a link in a new tab by adding target _blank attribute to the anchor tag. 
 But is there any way I can trigger every link in my website to open in new tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for a **CSS solution** only? or any solution like the one below (JQuery)

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

And also you can add the code below in your `head` tag-

```
<base target="_blank">
```

this will make all the `a` tags open in a new tab

Comment: I was looking for a JavaScript solution ,but I think <base target="_blank"> should do the work. Thanks.

Comment: @ShamimFahad If it works for you, please accept the answer, so the other will have a clear understanding

Comment: Adding target="_blank" to the <a href..> element did not work for me (windows 8.1, Chrome) but using <base..> worked. Tanks @Tanim

Answer (score 0):

Here is JS example and using with **onclick** handler

```
<div onclick="openInNewTab('www.example.com');">Click</div>

function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

https://www.tutsplanet.com/open-url-new-tab-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vanilla JavaScript with a `FOR` loop:

```
let links = document.links;

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
        links[i].target = '_blank';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open all link to a new tab by using html property `target="_blank"`

Just copy the **javascript** code and place:

```
 window.onload = function(){
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }
    }
```

**or** you can use the **jQuery** code:

before use this please ensure you added jquery on your project.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").attr("target", "_blank");
});
```